# Implement methods

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I was wondering if there is a way to implement a method in "Android Studio" at the begin of creating a class such as in Eclipse. When you create a class in Eclipse you have the option to add an superclass when you create a class, however, in AS you can only name the class and you have to put the methods manually by writing for instance "extends BroadcastReceiver" and then press ctrl+i to get the method list.

My question is if there is a auto-generator for superclass/methods in Android Studio or not?

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl-i` also **implements methods** of the super class in Android Studio/IntelliJ

Here is a [pdf](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) you can download with all the shortcuts for IntelliJ. This document is very handy to print out and keep posted next to your workstation. `ctrl-i` is on the left column on the 12th row. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the list, but I already know that. My question is if there is a way to generated it along with creating the class by itself.

Comment: IntelliJ/Android Studio does have a number of different shortcuts and simple wizard dialogs to generate code depending on the type of methods you want (Code > Generate). It's not universal because it really does depend on the type of methods you want implemented, but perhaps that functionality might work for you. See: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_generation.html

Answer (score 0):

After you create the class, you can hit alt-enter when selecting the class name - it should bring up the option to implement all the missing methods at once.